# Howto debug running bash script

Tags: linux, bash, debugging

I have a bash script running on Ubuntu.
Is it possible to see the line/command executed now without script restart.

The issue is that script sometimes never exits. This is really hard to reproduce (now I caught it), so I can't just stop the script and start the debugging.

Any help would be really appreciated

P.S. Script logic is hard to understand, so I can't to figure out why it's frozen by power of thoughts.

Comment: This is answered here: [Bash scripting, checking for errors, logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362255/bash-scripting-checking-for-errors-logging)
You can use the ">>" operator to insert commands which make entries into your error_log file.

Comment: The normal way to debug a shell script is to add `set -x` to the beginning, but that will require restarting it. The only suggestion I can think of is to use `strace`, but I don't know how easy it will be to translate its output into the script lines.

Comment: @FranzHolzinger How would he do that without restarting the script?

Comment: Of course the script must either have already generated somehow the output. Or the output commands must be inserted and the script restarted.

Comment: key note - "without restarting the script"

Comment: You could try intercepting what is going to `/dev/null` either globally by replacing `/dev/null` by a writable file (but you'll get lots of garbage), or change the fd for  `/dev/null` to another file with `gdb` with the `dup2` syscall for the Bash process. This will not give you exactly which line is being processed, but chances are that most output of the commands is sent there so it could give you some hints.

Comment: where is the output currently going ?

Comment: my comment was under the assumptions that the Bash script does not offer logs, of course

Comment: You can attach to running bash process using gdb and see backtrace. You will need bash debug symbols for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A running bash script is hung somewhere. Can I find out what line it is on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640794/a-running-bash-script-is-hung-somewhere-can-i-find-out-what-line-it-is-on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to find the process id (pid) of the shell, you may use `ps -ef | grep <script_name>`
Let's set this pid in the shell variable `$PID`.
Find all the child processes of this `$PID` by:

```
ps --ppid $PID
```

You might find one or more (if for example it's stuck in a pipelined series of commands). Repeat this command couple of times. If it doesn't change this means the script is stuck in certain command. In this case, you may attach trace command to the running child process:

```
sudo strace -p $PID
```

This will show you what is being executed, either indefinite loop (like reading from a pipe) or waiting on some event that never happens.

In case you find `ps --ppid $PID` changes, this indicates that your script is advancing but it's stuck somewhere, e.g. local loop in the script. From the changing commands, it can give you a hint where in the script it's looping.

Comment: Well, your approach gave me at least something. `code` sudo strace -p $PID `code` produce `code` read(3, `code` . Digit is file descriptor, using lsof I found that it's unix socket. So, script call for some system operation and wait for response from it using that socket. Unfortunately, that's not enough.

Comment: 1- What is command that this script is stuck at?

2- Could you share the output of `cat /proc/${PID}/fdinfo/3`

Comment: Unfortunately, bug is really rare ... I'l try to run the command next time it reproduces